# Module Mixin Instance Tracker

Tags: ruby, class, object, module, mixins

I have the following piece of code, which tracks how many instances there are of a class:

```
module InstanceTracker
  def self.instances
    counter = 0
    ObjectSpace.each_object do |i|
      if i.class == self
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    return counter
  end
end
```

What I want the end user to be able to do is:

```
class Foo
  include InstanceTracker
end
```

But when I do that, I get a `NoMethodError` for `Foo.instances`. It works fine if I make InstanceTracker a class and do this:

```
class Foo < InstanceTracker; end
```

How can I make it a module mixin?

Answer (score 2):

I played a little with your code. Apparently, you were comparing an instance's class with the caller, not the caller's class.
Try this:

```
module InstanceTracker
  def instances
    counter = 0
    ObjectSpace.each_object do |i|
      if i.class == self.class
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    return counter
  end
end
```

Worked for me.

Also, note that the `self` in `def self.instances` will cause your code to fail. For instance method declaration, use the method's simple name.

BTW, your code will cause the interpreter to iterate over every single object and test each one of them with each method call.
I suggest you hack the class' `new` method so it increments a class variable, making this variable accessible through an attribute reader.

Comment: +1! Also, shouldn't Foo `extend` not `include` InstanceTracker?